# Form-inline not printable in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap 4, using Beta 3, and I have a simple form-inline. When I go to print it the page prints as form-horizontal. Is this not working in Bootstrap 4? For obvious reasons, I really need this to print the same as it looks on the web page. Here is a simple example.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="form-control-label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control col" placeholder="email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a bug in Bootstrap 4 Beta 3 regarding this issue. I've just reported it and will update my answer when the bug gets fixed along with best practices to print inline forms.

Comment: Wow. That's great news. I found a hack that updates the CSS for Bootstrap 3 so that it prints form-inline on regular paper without shrinking down the formatting like it's a tiny Dymo label print. The hack isn't perfect, but it's close enough so I don't have to redo all my work as a standard webpage (i.e. non-mobile friendly) like in the 90's. I also looked into Foundation as a way to do this and it seems that people don't think mobile friendly pages need to be printed on regular paper anymore. Sigh.

Comment: I just saw your bug and it appears that you mentioned two separate issues. One - the d-print-* not appearing and Second the fields being stacked horizontally. They responded that it was a repeat of another bug and it was closed. But that bug was only re the d-print-* issue and not the form fields being stacked horizontally. Thus, the stacking issue will not be seen b/c it was closed out with the other related, but not the same, bug. Would you mind posting a bug that only addresses the stacking issue so it doesn't get lost?

Comment: OK, I've opened another one. Feel free to chime in and confirm here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25327

Comment: awesome. I posted a follow up to your bug.  :-)